# How to get java.lang.Type object of a self-defined class object?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I want to use Java `Generics` feature to implement a common functionality. But I don't know hot to get a `java.lang.reflect.Type` object for a self-defined class object. Following is my case that I want to get a Type from a given class name and pass it to `ProcessedResult<T>` to replace `T`:

```
String className = getClassName();
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Type type = null;
ProcessedResult<T> result = new ProcessedResult<T>();
```

I try to use `ProductModel.class.getGenericSuperclass()`, but as its name, it only return Type of its super class.

Can anybody gives me help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `java.lang.reflect.Type`? There is no `Type` in `java.lang`. Can you provide some code which shows your problem, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which we can run through javac to see the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by term *self-defined class object*?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar How is this related to Subversion?

Comment: Everybody, please see my updates of this question.

Comment: Class clazz = Class.forName(className).newInstance(); this code does not make sense! this method returns instance and not a class literal.

Comment: and if you want to get the `java.lang.reflect.Type` for any class then I have given the answer for it. what is the use of processed result class?

Comment: What's wrong with just `ProcessedResult<T> result = new ProcessedResult<T>();`? and leave out all the `clazz` and stuff

Answer (score 5):

You cannot specify a runtime-determined type as a compile time substitution for a generic type.

Your type `T` is actually only enforced at compile time [because of type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).  So by the time you have an actual type at runtime, any information or checks are already done and gone.

Your `ProcessedResult` will have to work with a `Class<T>` or `Type` object instead to do any useful work.

Answer (score 3):

`java.lang.reflect.Type` is **not** generic interface.

Also if you want the `Type` for use,

you can use `instance.getClass()` or `ClassName.class` as it returns `Class<?>` and `Class` implements `Type` interface. So it should work.

You will either have to use `ProcessedResult<Type>` or `ProcessedResult<Class<?>>`